# Action Intent causing a ActivityNotFoundException while starting another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

My TestApp which launches the activity has the following code:

```
public void startOperaView() {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("org.droidtv.nettvbrowser.VIEW");
        Uri luri = Uri.parse("connectedplanet.tv/olvs/test");

        //browserIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Browser.class);
        //browserIntent.setAction("org.droidtv.nettvbrowser.VIEW");
        browserIntent.setType("application/vnd.droidtv.sta");
        browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        browserIntent.setData(luri);

        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

And the package "org.droidtv.nettvbrowser" has the following AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
            android:name="org.droidtv.nettvbrowser.Browser"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="org.droidtv.nettvbrowser.VIEW" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.droidtv.sta" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The weird part is that if I specify the actual package name in the intent it seems to work fine, Only the action intents are throwing these errors.Any help would be appreciated.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html and you can try set `android:exported="true"`

```
android:exported
```

Whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.
The default value depends on whether the activity contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that the activity can be invoked only by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the activity is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the activity is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".

This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission attribute).

Or you can refer to something like this:

```
<activity android:name="OutgoingCallBroadcaster"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
    <!-- CALL action intent filters, for the various ways
         of initiating an outgoing call. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_sip_call">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="sip" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="voicemail" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I used the android:exported tag too. No luck. I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to separate your two intent actions/categories?

Comment: Can you please elaborate by what you mean? I'm new to android.